# why does caret triggers a css lint error?

Tags: css, emmet

I had this emmet code typed

```
tr>td>input[type="submit"]^^tr>td+td>input[type="submit"]
```

which outputs:

```
<tr>
 <td><input type="submit" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><input type="submit" /></td>
</tr>
```

however when I used "caret" ^ in my css

```
input[type="submit"]^^tr>td+td>input[type="submit"]
{
 display: none;
}
```

css lint triggers an error. unexpected token '^'

What is the equivalent symbol of double caret (^^) in css?
tr>td>input[type="submit"]^^tr>td+td>input[type="submit"]

Thank you!

Comment: there is no `^^` in css! can you explain what you tried to do?  Also here is selector in css: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: thank you answering. I want to hide the second input[type="submit"] button next to the first input submit button which is inside the tr and inside the td.

Comment: Could you show your full code ? otherwise from what's provided you could just `tr+tr>td:nth-child(2)>input{display:none;}` which i'm sure isn't exactly what you looking for

Comment: This is my bin:
https://jsbin.com/bogojan/edit?html,css,output

I want the submit button disabled when .disagree radio button is checked. 

Thanks!